# i can't generate my report with jasperReport and struts2

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

i'm trying to implement jasper report with struts2,for now i can't get my report.i do realy nead help,here is my struts.xml

```
<struts>

<package extends="jasperreports-default" name="default" namespace="/">  
    <result-types>  
        <result-type class="org.apache.struts2.views.jasperreports.JasperReportsResult" name="jasper"/>  

    </result-types>
    <action class="action.JasperAction" name="StrutsJasperAction" method="execute">  
        <result name="success" type="jasper">  
            <param name="location">/jasper/sample.jasper</param>  
            <param name="dataSource">stList</param>  
            <param name="format">PDF</param>  
        </result>  
    </action>  
</package>
</struts>
```

and i want to know in  what location should i do.here is my structure of my app.
[image]

and in my action JasperAction what should i do at JasperCompileReportToFile.compileReportToFile(....??????) .

```
try {  
            JasperCompileManager.compileReportToFile(  
                    "D:/Test/workspace/testJasper/WebContent/jasper/sample.jrxml",  
                    "D:/Test/workspace/testJasper/WebContent/jasper/sample.jasper");  
        } catch (Exception e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
            return ERROR;  
        }
```

if you need more details just ask.

Comment: there is a tutorial/example here http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/jasperreports-tutorial.html

Comment: and a step by step guide here http://devjasperreports-ravindra.blogspot.ie

Comment: @hob,thanks for reply,i was following this tuto http://blog.sandeepgupta.info/2011/04/integrate-jasper-reports-with-struts2.html?showComment=1368539077930#c8860260505101632405 but whene i run it nothing happens.i don't see my report